# Jconsole applet monitoring : Which process to monitor?

Tags: java, applet, monitor, jconsole

I want to monitor a java applet for memory usage, using jconsole in Windows, and i would like to find out which process is the one that i should focus in.

[image: jconsole menu processes]

On the image i posted appear two processes which jconsole is able to connect to.
I am 100% sure that no other java process is executed except for a firefox instance running the applet.

The empty named process (PID 5152) is firefox.exe, and the "sun.plugin2.manin..." (PID 5628) named one is java.exe, according to windows task manager.

So which one should i monitor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect to the process starting with 'sun.plugin2'. The firefox process is the parent of the 'sun.plugin2' process.

Comment: Thank you, i was leading that way also, but the following article from oracle states that the empty name process should be chosen.
https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_instrumented_applets_monitoring_and
Could you explain why i should monitor the other one?

Comment: It is a bit tricky since JDK changes all the time. According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-141751.html. Java From SE 6 update 10, "Rather than executing applets in a Java™ virtual machine (JVM) instance which is embedded in the web browser's process, the JVM instance which executes the applet is now a separate process from the web browser."

Comment: Even though you might find jconsole can connect to and monitor your 'empty' process, I would advise you to just monitor the child process only. Moreover, in development or test stages, you might even be interested to run it using appletviewer, where it runs as a standalone process. This way, what you see is more likely to reflect your program behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot alfredx for the elaborate answer. 
Appletviewer is a much more clean way to test as it seems!